# How to make a hash of all vowels in a string?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have googled it everywhere ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769800/trying-to-find-vowels-of-a-string-using-ruby-while-loops), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835078/searching-for-vowels-in-ruby), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298481/regular-expression-in-ruby-to-get-all-vowels-in-string)) but strangely I could not find it.

I have a string, `str = "make stackoverflow great again"`. How can I make a hash of all the vowel occurrences in that string? `{"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "i"=>1, "o"=>2, "u"=>0}`

Right now I have the most obtuse, least-ruby-like method:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  list = {}
  a = string.count("a")
  e = string.count("e")
  i = string.count("i")
  o = string.count("o")
  u = string.count("u")

  list["a"] = a
  list["e"] = e
  list["i"] = i
  list["o"] = o
  list["u"] = u

  list
end
```

What is the most ruby-esque way to make a hash of all the vowels in any given string?

Comment: The answers below are good. If you want to count all vowels by the way you can try something like `str.scan(/[aeoui]/).count`

Comment: So "everywhere" is three places and they're all in Stack Overflow?

Comment: `str.scan(/[aeoui]/).count # => 11`. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to include an O(n) solution since the prior are all O(n^2).

```
str.gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "").each_char.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |vowel, hash| hash[vowel] += 1 }
=> {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "o"=>2, "i"=>1}
```

Determining the Big O notation of this isn't perfect, so bear with me.

Step 1 - O(n)

```
str.gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "")
=> "aeaoeoeaaai"
```

This step loops through the string characters and removes consonants.  I did my best to try and find the actual runtime of gsub but without doing my own benchmarks I can't *really* be sure.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173648/3109182) when originally writing my answer but it is also not ironclad.  `gsub` should find all indexes that match the expression and return those values as a new string.

Step 2 - O(n)

```
each_char
```

Simply takes the string returned and returns an Enumerator.  Depending on the language, turning a string into an array of strings/chars has at worst a runtime of the length of the string (hence O(n)).  With ruby, returning an Enumerator is actually lazily evaluated so you could argue here we're in O(1).

Step 3 - O(n)

```
each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |vowel, hash| hash[vowel] += 1 }
```

There are multiple sub-steps here:

Step 3a - Instantiate a new Hash object O(1) who's default value is 0.

Step 3b - Assign/find the key (vowel) in the hash - average O(1), worst case O(n)

Step 3c - Increment that value by 1 - O(1)

Step 3d - Loop through each letter - O(n)

So that means from our 3 steps we have O(n) + O(n) + O(n) which is really O(3n) but Big O states we can drop constants like 3 in this instance, so it just becomes O(n).

I myself am also still learning Big O so this explanation could likely use some community input.

Comment: Removing the consonents at the beginning is a good idea. Two small suggestions: 1) use `each_char` rather than `chars`, to avoid the creation of an intermediate array; and 2) use `each_with_object` rather than `inject` to get rid of that pesky `; hash`.

Comment: @Anthony if it is not too much, would you mind briefly explaining why it is an O(n) solution? I am also learning about big oh and would like to know the differences in actual code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! I saw that it has been edited. Much appreciate it! Read through it and it makes a lot of sense, too!

Comment: I prefer  `str.delete("^aeiou")` over  `str.gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "")` .

Answer (score 3):

Consider such solution:

```
str    = 'make stackoverflow great again'
vowels = %w(a e o u i)
vowels.each_with_object({}) {|vowel, hash| hash[vowel] = str.count(vowel) }
#=> {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "o"=>2, "u"=>0, "i"=>1}
```

Comment: This is somewhat inefficient as `count` traverses the string once for each vowel, rather than just once.

Comment: @CarySwoveland from the [the Tin Man's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39380281/1772830) we can see, that my answer holds the fastest along with seph's one :) But indeed you're right about traversing each time

Answer (score 3):

```
%w(a e o u i).map{ |v| {v => str.count(v)} }.reduce(:merge)
```

Comment: this won't return the desired result ;) you'll need to add `inject({}, :merge)` to be compliant with what OP wants

Comment: with `inject`/`reduce` you do not need to do `&:merge`, it can be simply `:merge` :)

Comment: You could do it like this: `%w(a e o u i).map { |v| [v, str.count(v)] }.to_h`

Comment: @seph I actually think your version is better, you should post it as an answer

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yep, that is what I said when it was `&:merge` :) Check out revisions

Comment: @Andrew, sorry, 'twas a dyslexia moment.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a *counting hash* so that the characters of the string are only traversed once. See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

```
VOWELS = "aeiou"

h = str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 if VOWELS.include?(c) }
  #=> {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "o"=>2, "i"=>1}
```

Note that `h["u"] #=> 0`.

If the string is large, you should be able to speed this up by putting the vowels in a set (and making no other changes).

```
require 'set'

VOWELS = "aeiou".each_char.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}>
```

Better would be to remove the consonents from the string at the onset, as @Anthony has done.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "make stackoverflow great again"
vowels = %w{a e i o u}

vowels.map { |v| [v, str.count(v)] }.to_h
#> {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "i"=>1, "o"=>2, "u"=>0}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it something like this:

```
str = "make stackoverflow great again"

str.scan(/[aeiou]/).each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = 0}) { |v, h| h[v] += 1 }
# => {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "o"=>2, "i"=>1}
```

But, just for fun, here's a benchmark:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'set'

str = "make stackoverflow great again"
vowels = 'aeiou'
vowels_set = vowels.each_char.to_set
vowels_ary = vowels.chars
vowels_regex = /[aeiou]/
vowels_not_regex = /[^aeiou]/

compare do
  ttm      { str.scan(vowels_regex).each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = 0}) { |v, h| h[v] += 1 } }
  Andrey_Deineko { vowels_ary.each_with_object({}) {|vowel, hash| hash[vowel] = str.count(vowel) } }
  Anthony  { str.gsub(vowels_not_regex, "").each_char.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |vowel, hash| hash[vowel] += 1 } }
  dimid    { vowels_ary.map{ |v| {v => str.count(v)} }.reduce(:merge) }
  cary_str { str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 if vowels.include?(c) } }
  cary_set { str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 if vowels_set.include?(c) } }
  seph     { vowels_ary.map { |v| [v, str.count(v)] }.to_h }
end

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 3 seconds.
# >> Andrey_Deineko is similar to seph
# >> seph is faster than cary_str by 4x ± 1.0 (results differ: {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "i"=>1, "o"=>2, "u"=>0} vs {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "o"=>2, "i"=>1})
# >> cary_str is similar to dimid (results differ: {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "o"=>2, "i"=>1} vs {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "i"=>1, "o"=>2, "u"=>0})
# >> dimid is similar to ttm (results differ: {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "i"=>1, "o"=>2, "u"=>0} vs {"a"=>5, "e"=>3, "o"=>2, "i"=>1})
# >> ttm is similar to cary_set
# >> cary_set is similar to Anthony
```

---

> I'd be curious how the length of str impacts performance of the below solutions.

First, ahem, the code is right there. Copy it, paste it into your editor, change the string and experiment, right?

By changing the size of the initial `str` to 100x longer:

```
str = "make stackoverflow great again" * 100
```

the results change to:

```
# >> Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 29 seconds.
# >> Andrey_Deineko is similar to seph
# >> seph is faster than dimid by 2x ± 0.1
# >> dimid is faster than ttm by 55x ± 10.0 (results differ: {"a"=>500, "e"=>300, "i"=>100, "o"=>200, "u"=>0} vs {"a"=>500, "e"=>300, "o"=>200, "i"=>100})
# >> ttm is faster than Anthony by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
# >> Anthony is faster than cary_str by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> cary_str is similar to cary_set
```

Comment: does fruity vary the size of `str` at all?  I'd be curious how the length of `str` impacts performance of the below solutions.  Thanks for putting that all together!

Comment: No, Fruity makes no changes. Why would it do that? The length of the string makes a difference because there are more potential character candidates to consider as the string grows. The algorithms that reduce the string before processing, or that efficiently use the built-in C-based methods, will be fastest at that point.